# Ruby / Rails Groups only Adjacent Array Elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have a sorted array full of objects which I'd like to group by an attribute, but only if they're adjacent in the array.

`a` is sorted by the `start` attribute.

`a = [{name: "joe", start: "9am", end: "10am"},
    {name: "joe", start: "10am", end: "11am"},
    {name: "harry", start: "11am", end: "12pm"},
    {name: "harry", start: "12pm", end: "1pm"},
    {name: "harry", start: "1pm", end: "2pm"},
    {name: "joe", start: "2pm", end: "3pm"},
    {name: "joe", start: "3pm", end: "4pm"}]`

I would like to group adjacent objects by the `name` attribute so the results looks like:

```
a = [[{name: "joe", start: "9am", end: "10am"},{name: "joe", start: "10am", end: "11am"}],
    [{name: "harry", start: "11am", end: "12pm"},{name: "harry", start: "12pm", end: "1pm"},{name: "harry", start: "1pm", end: "2pm"}],
    [{name: "joe", start: "2pm", end: "3pm"},{name: "joe", start: "3pm", end: "4pm"}]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
a.chunk {|hash| hash[:name]}.map(&:last)
```