# Ruby / Rails Group Array Based on Comparing Adjacent Elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have a sorted array full of objects which I'd like to group by comparing them to their surrounding elements.

`a` is sorted by the `start` attribute.

```
 a = [{ name: "joe",   start: "9am",  end: "10am" },
      { name: "joe",   start: "10am", end: "11am" },
      { name: "harry", start: "11am", end: "12pm" },
      { name: "harry", start: "12pm", end: "1pm"  },
      { name: "harry", start: "2pm",  end: "3pm"  },
      { name: "joe",   start: "3pm",  end: "4pm"  },
      { name: "joe",   start: "4pm",  end: "5pm"  }]
```

I would like to group adjacent objects by the `name` attribute but only if the `start` and `end` times are the same, producing:

```
    a = [[{ name: "joe",   start: "9am",  end: "10am" }, { name: "joe",   start: "10am", end: "11am" }],
         [{ name: "harry", start: "11am", end: "12pm" }, { name: "harry", start: "12pm", end: "1pm"  }],
         [{ name: "harry", start: "2pm",  end: "3pm"  }],
         [{ name: "joe",   start: "3pm",  end: "4pm"  }, { name: "joe",   start: "4pm",  end: "5pm"  }]]
```

There is no maximum to the amount of consecutive time periods.

---

I can group them by `name` if adjacent as seen here: [Ruby / Rails Groups only Adjacent Array Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323620/ruby-rails-groups-only-adjacent-array-elements)

```
a.chunk { |hash| hash[:name] }.map(&:last)
```

But it doesn't appear as though I can get the element index with chunk to do the `start` `end` time comparisons.

---

It looks like the answer is here: [Grouping an array by comparing 2 adjacent elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024521/grouping-an-array-by-comparing-2-adjacent-elements)

But I'm failing miserably at writing my own function. (I'm struggling to understand what `slice_before` does.)

```
def self.group_by(data)
  tmp = data.first
  data.slice_before do |item|
    tmp, prev = item, tmp
    item.application == prev.application &&
      item.start == prev.end
  end.to_a
  return data
end
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So you want to group adjacent times for the same person?

Comment: Is the maximum two? Or are there potentially many?

Comment: No maximum, there's potentially many.

Comment: Many in a group you mean?

Comment: Yes, many consecutive time periods

Comment: Yes, there's no maximum consecutive time periods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) and [`Enumerable#slice_when`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when). It requires Ruby 2.2+, though.

```
require 'time' # for sorting times

a = [{ name: "joe",   start: "9am",  end: "10am" },
     { name: "joe",   start: "10am", end: "11am" },
     { name: "harry", start: "11am", end: "12pm" },
     { name: "harry", start: "12pm", end: "1pm"  },
     { name: "harry", start: "2pm",  end: "3pm"  },
     { name: "joe",   start: "3pm",  end: "4pm"  },
     { name: "joe",   start: "4pm",  end: "5pm"  }]

a.sort_by { |h| [ h[:name], Time.parse(h[:start]) ] }                     # 1
 .slice_when { |x, y| x[:end] != y[:start] || x[:name] != y[:name] }.to_a # 2
```

which yields

```
=> [[{:name=>"harry", :start=>"11am", :end=>"12pm"}, {:name=>"harry", :start=>"12pm", :end=>"1pm"}],
    [{:name=>"harry", :start=>"2pm", :end=>"3pm"}],
    [{:name=>"joe", :start=>"9am", :end=>"10am"}, {:name=>"joe", :start=>"10am", :end=>"11am"}],
    [{:name=>"joe", :start=>"3pm", :end=>"4pm"}, {:name=>"joe", :start=>"4pm", :end=>"5pm"}]]
```

Here's a step-by-step explanation with intermediate results:

1) Sort the hashes by name and then by time within name. Note the use of `Time.parse` to temporarily convert your time string into a `Time` object for proper sorting:

```
 => [{:name=>"harry", :start=>"11am", :end=>"12pm"},
     {:name=>"harry", :start=>"12pm", :end=>"1pm"},
     {:name=>"harry", :start=>"2pm", :end=>"3pm"},
     {:name=>"joe", :start=>"9am", :end=>"10am"},
     {:name=>"joe", :start=>"10am", :end=>"11am"},
     {:name=>"joe", :start=>"3pm", :end=>"4pm"},
     {:name=>"joe", :start=>"4pm", :end=>"5pm"}]
```

2) Now slice this intermediate array when the end time of the former is not equal to the start time of the latter or when the names don't match using Daniel Polfer's solution. This returns an `Enumerator` object, hence the final `to_a` method call:

```
=> [[{:name=>"harry", :start=>"11am", :end=>"12pm"}, {:name=>"harry", :start=>"12pm", :end=>"1pm"}],
    [{:name=>"harry", :start=>"2pm", :end=>"3pm"}],
    [{:name=>"joe", :start=>"9am", :end=>"10am"}, {:name=>"joe", :start=>"10am", :end=>"11am"}],
    [{:name=>"joe", :start=>"3pm", :end=>"4pm"}, {:name=>"joe", :start=>"4pm", :end=>"5pm"}]]
```

If your hashes are already presorted, then Daniel Polfer's solution should work fine. But if you have any data where names and/or start times are out of order like this:

```
b = [{:name=>"joe", :start=>"3pm", :end=>"4pm"},
     {:name=>"bill", :start=>"2pm", :end=>"3pm"},
     {:name=>"joe", :start=>"5pm", :end=>"6pm"},
     {:name=>"joe", :start=>"4pm", :end=>"5pm"}]
```

Just using `slice_when` returns

```
=> [[{:name=>"joe", :start=>"3pm", :end=>"4pm"}],
    [{:name=>"bill", :start=>"2pm", :end=>"3pm"}],
    [{:name=>"joe", :start=>"5pm", :end=>"6pm"}],
    [{:name=>"joe", :start=>"4pm", :end=>"5pm"}]]
```

instead of

```
=> [[{:name=>"bill", :start=>"2pm", :end=>"3pm"}],
    [{:name=>"joe", :start=>"3pm", :end=>"4pm"},
     {:name=>"joe", :start=>"4pm", :end=>"5pm"},
     {:name=>"joe", :start=>"5pm", :end=>"6pm"}]]
```

Comment: Just consecutive runs by name is what I'm after. Which is the result of step 4. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: DanielPolfer answer seems nice and simple. `a.slice_when{|h1,h2| (h1[:name]!=h2[:name]) || (h1[:end]!=h2[:start])}.to_a1` any reason not to go for that?

Comment: I don't think there as any reason not to go for that @RyanKing. That is a significant improvement over mine.

Comment: @RyanKing There's one tiny issue with Daniel's answer that I touch on above. Still think his is better, though.

Comment: so as long as sort the data by `start` first than Daniels answer should work fine, right?

Comment: It should be sorted by name and (start) time within name to work properly in all cases, but you should test on your own data to make sure.

Comment: I suppose it makes this the more reliable solution though

Answer (score 2):

Verbose, but gives result in order you presented, and works with older versions of Ruby...

```
a.inject([]) do |result,hash| 
  if (!result.empty? && 
      (result.last.last[:name] == hash[:name]) && 
      (result.last.last[:end] == hash[:start]))
    result.last << hash
  else
    result << [hash]
  end
  result
end
```

Builds the result one hash at a time, choosing to add a hash to the end of the last array or "step" to a new final array entry.

---

Ruby 2.2+

`a.slice_when{|h1,h2| (h1[:name]!=h2[:name]) || (h1[:end]!=h2[:start])}.to_a`

Comment: Nice! Works a treat! The ruby 2.2 version is a bit cleaner though.

Comment: a.slice_when{|h1,h2| (h1[:name]!=h2[:name]) || (h1[:end]!=h2[:start])}.to_a leverages off the other answer for 2.2, but cuts it down a bit for same result.  Just slices in place.

Comment: Ooo that's a pretty simple approach!

Comment: @DanielPolfer Nice! You should add that to your answer. That is a lot simpler than mine!

Answer (score 0):

Using slice_before:

```
y=a[0]
a.slice_before { |hash| x=y 
                        y = hash
                        x[:name] != y[:name] || x[:end] != y[:start]
                        }.to_a
```